# Show that a binary operation on $\omega_1$ is not commutative

Tags: set-theory

Let $\star$ be a binary operation on $\omega_1$ such that:

i) For all $\alpha\in\omega_1$ we have $\alpha\star2>\alpha$

ii) For all $\lambda\in\omega_1$ limit and $\alpha\in\omega_1$ we have $\alpha\star\lambda=$sup$\{\alpha\star\beta:\beta\in\lambda\}$

Show that $\star$ is not commutative.

I was trying to get a contradiction to commutativity building increasing sequences but that did not get me anywhere...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\star$ were to be commutative, then $f(\alpha) = \sup_{\beta\le\alpha} 2\star \beta$ would both preserve limits and satisfy $f(\alpha)>\alpha$. Therefore the limit of
$$ 0, f(0), f(f(0)), \ldots, f^n(0), \ldots $$
must be a fixed point (and is below $\omega_1$ because $\omega_1$ is regular), which is a contradiction.

Comment: I thought about that but I cannot prove that the function is increasing because of case 0

Comment: @WrabbitW: A bounded set doesn't matter when talking about clubs and normal functions.

Comment: @WrabbitW: Hmm, minor braino, the word "increasing" was wrong. Rewording.

Comment: Okay I got it, you show that the function is normal in a club and then use fix point theorem for clubs. Thanks